# What is the distribution of the error term in the Poisson Regression model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, error, poisson-regression

Given a Poisson regression model as $y = E(y\mid x) + ε$ where $λ = E(y\mid x) = \exp(x'β)$ with $y$ from the Poisson distribution ($\operatorname{Poisson}(λ)$) I am trying to understand the distribution of $ε$. I tried writing the error term as $ε = y - E(y\mid x) = y - λ$ and obtained the PMF of $ε$ as $P(ε = k) = P(y = k+λ) = {λ^{k+λ}e^{-λ}}/{(k+λ)!}$. So can it be concluded that the error term of the Poisson model follow a distribution with the obtained PMF or there is a known distribution that the error term follows?

Comment: This is not a Poisson regression model.  There is no "error term."  The correct model is $E[y\mid x] = \exp(x^\prime \beta).$

Comment: @whuber I would say the model is $$ y\mid x \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\exp(x'\beta)). $$

Comment: @Michael Thank you, that is more explicit.  I chose the form I did in order to emulate the OP's attempt.

Comment: A similar question with a similar answer:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124818/logistic-regression-error-term-and-its-distribution

Answer (score 6):

@whuber's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579155/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-error-term-in-the-poisson-regression-model#comment1069460_579155) is the answer.  Typically we don't assume an independent error term with non-normal generalized linear models.  The response distribution already contains the theorized stochastic elements of the situation.  In the context of a Poisson GLM, we assume that the expected value of the inverse transformed linear predictor (the most common link would be the log) is equal to the parameter ($\lambda$) that controls the behavior of the conditional response distribution.  The observed datum is seen as a realized value drawn from that distribution.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your response. But I am wondering about the error terms if we write the model in a traditional way as indicated in my question.

Comment: That's not a useful way to analyze the model or even to think about it, because *you get a different conditional distribution for every explanatory value!*

Comment: @Dick, it is incorrect to write this model like that.  That is a "tradidional way" to write a linear model, but it is not a traditional (or correct) way to write a Poisson GLM.

Comment: I totally understand you points. I am just following the lecture notes of my course and it is defined in the way presented in my question which seems confusing to me too.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a tough one, @Dick.  You'll need to ask the lecturer what they have in mind.  The traditional formulation of the Poisson GLM doesn't work like that, so I can't say what they're thinking.

Comment: You're welcome, @Dick.

Comment: I have used this linear form with error term $\epsilon$ as well in an answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466212/). For me it is sort of like a multistable perception where there is a transition between two images that is difficult to see, the conditional probability expression $\pi(z;\theta,\phi) = \exp \left[ \alpha(\phi) \lbrace z\theta - g(\theta)  +h(z)\rbrace +\beta(\phi,z) \right]$ and the itterated reweighted regression. Thinking of the Poisson or other regression, in terms of a linear added term helps me to intuitively transition between those two images.